# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined React Native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, api

I am trying to call API data with axios.
I am getting a response with console.log. Although the response is not showing on the screen. Really stuck with this.

```
export default class PrivacyPolicyScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: null, 
    }
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    return fetch ('API', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'x-api-key': 'KEy'
    },
    })
    .then( (response)=> response.json() )
    .then ( (responseJson) => {
      console.log ("This is the response that should be in the app", {responseJson})
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson.terms,
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  };
    render () {
      if (this.state.isLoading){
        return (
          <Text >Loading Privacy!!!!</Text>
        ) 
      } else { 
        let privpolicy = this.state.responseJson.map((val, key ) => {
          return <View key={key}>
            <Text >{val.dataSource}</Text>
          </View>
        })
      return (
        {privpolicy}
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` The undefined object is on Line 42. I have tried `componentWillMount` and several other iterations. I am really struggling finding the solution here.

Comment: Why do you have the curly braces in your console.log? If you console.log `responseJson.terms`, does it show what it is meant to show? An array?

Comment: I get `undefined` when I run. `console.log (responseJson.terms)`

Comment: That means that you are trying to map something that doesn't exist. Log the `responseJson` and set what you need from it, but `terms` is undefined it seems. Then refer to @Kerchik answer.

Comment: Great this has revealed:`this.state.dataSource.map is not a function` on line 38

Comment: Can you share the `responseJson` object that you are receiving? First you gotta set the response properly to the state, we'll deal with the second error later.

Comment: `what does this do?  Private Policies here ...` This is what I get from the `console.log` That is the info I want.

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't map the response is because you are not receiving an array to be able to map it (you can use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) only with arrays).

So, judging by your answers, you are receiving a string (text), which you then want to display. In order to do that, you'll have to do something as follows:

```
componentDidMount () {
    return fetch ('API', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'x-api-key': 'KEy'
    },
    })
    .then( (response)=> response.json() )
    .then ( (responseJson) => {
      console.log ("This is the response that should be in the app", {responseJson})
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson,
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  };

    render () {
      if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
          <Text >Loading Privacy!!!!</Text>
        ) 
      } else if (this.state.dataSource) { 
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>{this.state.dataSource}</Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
      return null;
}
```

I've also added an additional check for the `this.state.dataSource`, although that's just something I personally like to do, you can remove it.

Try it like that and tell me if that works.

Comment: Thank you so much that works perfectly! Although I needed to adjust the `dataSource` to reflect the correct info. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

You are mapping responseJson property, that does not exist in state. If i understood correctly, you stored response data to dataSource, so your map operation should look like this:

```
let privpolicy = this.state.dataSource.map((val, key ) => {}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using wrong variable that not even defined in state declaration.I would suggest you to change your render part as follows

```
   let privpolicy = this.state.dataSource.map((val, key ) => {
      return <View key={key}>
        <Text >{val.dataSource}</Text>
      </View>
    })
```

hope it works for you.